# Font for inline Listings is not changing

Tags: fonts, listings

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX and use `\lstinline{}` a lot. The problem is that the font on the output does not change to '`this`', but rather continue like 'this'. How do I correct this behaviour?

I have compiled my document in Sublime Text 2 with LaTeXTools on Ubuntu and Windows, and with MikTeX on Windows. Everything gives the same output.

Comment: the manual said that `\lstinline` with `{ }` is still experimental.

Comment: @selwyndd21 I have been using this for around 2 years now. I have used in project reports, seminar reports, etc. But, the thing is, I had not written the preamble there. I got it as a template. So I did not know about this. I thought it would be a default behavior of LaTex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) sets the font style in the default font, unless you specify it to be different using the `basicstyle` key. For a global setting of the basic style to typewriter font, add

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
```

to your document preamble. It's use is discussed on p 30 of the `listings` documentation:

> ```
> basicstyle=<basic style>
> ```
>
> (default `{}`) is selected at the beginning of each listing. You could use `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\itshape`, `\ttfamily`, or something like that. The last token of `<basic style>` must not read any following characters.